# Pause Until Action Problem

Tags: workflow

If condition is status 1, workflow will send an email but if an action was not done, I need to send a follow-up email that is why I used 'pause until' action.

My problem is when an action is done and I changed the condition to status 2, workflow is still in the pause mood since it was triggered above.

How will the workflow ignore the pause action when condition has changed?

Will greatly appreciate your advise on this.

Thank you.

Resty

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of your workflow?

Comment: @mihail-florin popa, here's the code: If Current Item:Status equals Assigned to line manager for action
    Email Current Item:Manager
    Pause Until Current Item:FollowUp Date equals Today     Then Email Current Item:Manager                                        If Current Item:Status equals Report submitted by line manager             Email Current Item:Manager